# How to manipulate lists in R by adding commas, parentheses between list elements and sort them alphabetically

Tags: r, list

Hello i have a short list, as reproducible example, which includes country names and US State names.

```
**LIST<-list(list(c("USA","WY","TE","AZ","Canada"),list(c("USA","Canada","CAL","WY")),list(c("USA","Australia","CAL","AR")))**
```

As i want to display this list as data frame column later in a shiny data table (and pdf report) i would like to know how could I edit its elements by adding commas between the words, putting States inside parentheses and sort States alphabetically.

An example of what i would like to achieve is the following:

**USA (AL, AZ, CA, CO,
CT, DE, DC, FL, GA, IL,
),
Australia, Canada,
Israel, Korea, Mexico,
Switzerland, Taiwan**

After USA and its states the rest of the countries should be displayed alphabetically.

Comment: How do you distinguish between states and countries?

Comment: How do you know what's a state and what's a country? We can't use two letter abbreviations, as you've got "CAL", and they're not the official abbreviations, as you've got "TE". Also, what to do with the multiple lists? Should they be separate text lines? See if you can make your sample input and sample output match up, they don't now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create a function named `foo` to return a logical vector which corresponding which element in `x` is a state (by assuming the state is abbreviated in upper cases, except "USA" itself). If you have other countries abbreviated in upper cases, for examples, "UK" and "UAE", you can replace `x == 'USA'` with `x %in% c('USA', 'UAE', 'UK')`.

```
foo <- function(x){
  if(x == 'USA'){
    foo <- FALSE
  }else{
    foo <- toupper(x)  == x
  }
}
```

Next, obtain a vector of states from each item in the list using the `sapply` function. Here is a tricky part. As the second and the third elements of `LIST` are also a `list` object with one element, you need to use the `sapply` on the first element in these `list` objects as follow. Of course, the following can be written more elegantly using by checking the class of each element in `LIST` using a for-loop or `apply` family functions.

```
 LIST <- list(c("USA","WY","TE","AZ","Canada"),list(c("USA","Canada","CAL","WY")),list(c("USA","Australia","CAL","AR")))


us1 <- LIST[[1]][sapply(LIST[[1]],  function(y){foo(y)}) ] 
us2 <- LIST[[2]][[1]][sapply(LIST[[2]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})]
us3 <- LIST[[3]][[1]][sapply(LIST[[3]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})]
```

Then you can bind `us1`, `us2`, and `us2` as a vector. Remove the duplicates by applying `unique` function before sorting them alphabetically.

```
state   <- sort(unique(c(us1, us2, us3)))
```

The result is

```
> state 
[1] "AR"  "AZ"  "CAL" "TE"  "WY"
```

Similarly, you can obtain countries by getting elements which are not states:

```
co1 <- LIST[[1]][ !sapply(LIST[[1]],  function(y){foo(y)}) ] 
co2 <- LIST[[2]][[1]][ !sapply(LIST[[2]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})]
co3 <- LIST[[3]][[1]][ !sapply(LIST[[3]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})]

country <- sort(unique(c(co1, co2, co3)))
```

As you need to begin your string with `USA`, so drop it from `country`.

```
country <- country[!(country %in% 'USA')]
```

Finally, let's create a string named `myString` by initialising with `'USA ('`.

```
myString <- 'USA ('
```

Then, concatenate `myString` with each element from `state`.

```
for(i in 1:length(state)){

  if(i == length(state)){
    myString <- paste0(myString,state[i], "), ")
  }else{
    myString <- paste0(myString,state[i], ", ")
  }
}
```

Do the same for `country`

```
for(i in 1:length(country)){

  if(i == length(country)){
    myString <- paste0(myString,country[i])
  }else{
    myString <- paste0(myString,country[i], ", ")
  }

}
```

The result is:

```
myString
[1] "USA (AR, AZ, CAL, TE, WY), Australia, Canada"
```

**Update**

The list should contain ***multiple*** lists. For example, say `LIST` is defined as:

```
LIST <- list(list(c("USA","WY","TX","AZ","Canada", "CA", "NY", 'Russia', 'NY')), 
             list(c("USA","Canada","CA","WY", 'China', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'WY')), 
             list(c("USA","Australia","CA","AR", 'AZ', 'WY', 'New Zealand', 'Japan', 'Japan', 'NJ')),
             list(c('Australia', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'Malaysia' )),
             list(c('USA', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'Malaysia' )))
```

**Note that some lists in `LIST` contain duplicate states and countries. Some lists contain neither states nor `USA`. Then, we can modify codes above to cater different scenarios and store the result in a list named `output` by using a `for` loop as following**:

```
output <- list()
for(i in 1:length(LIST)){
  country  <- sort( unique( LIST[[i]][[1]][ !sapply(LIST[[i]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})  ] ))
  USAcheck <- any( country %in% 'USA')
  country  <- country[! country %in% 'USA']
  state    <- sort( unique( LIST[[i]][[1]][ sapply(LIST[[i]][[1]], function(y){foo(y)})  ] ))


  if(USAcheck){

    if( length(state) > 0){
      myString <- 'USA ('

      for(j in 1:length(state)){
        if(j == length(state)){
          myString <- paste0(myString, state[j], "), ")
        }else{
          myString <- paste0(myString, state[j], ", ")

        }
      }
    }else{
      myString <- 'USA, '
    }



  }else{
    myString <- ''
  }



  for(j in 1:length(country)){

    if(j == length(country)){
      myString <- paste0(myString, country[j])
    }else{
      myString <- paste0(myString, country[j], ", ")
    }

  }
  output[[i]] <- list( myString )

}
```

The result looks like

```
>output
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "USA (AZ, CA, NY, TX, WY), Canada, Russia"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "USA (AZ, CA, WY), Canada, China"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "USA (AR, AZ, CA, NJ, WY), Australia, Japan, New Zealand"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "Australia, Japan, Malaysia"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "USA, Australia, Japan, Malaysia"
```

Comment: Hello, as you said my initial list "LIST" includes 3 lists. The final result should be another list with the same 3 lists but with the logic i described implemented on them.

Comment: Hello @firmo23, the example you gave is not a list of 3 lists. It is a list with a vector as the first item and the other two as lists. If it is a list of 3 lists, the codes would be different. In light of this, do you mind to edit your question for clarity?

Comment: You are totally correct. I forgot a list() and this is why i still cannot implement your wonderful answer. Could you adapt your answer?

Comment: @firmo23 I tweaked the codes and hopefully it achieved what you expect.

Comment: It helps. But what if a list does not contain USA and its states at all? It stills sticks the "USA (" to it.

Comment: @firmo23, GOOD catch! I have adapted this scenario.

Comment: This indeed works! So i ll use it. Could this exact new list be displayed in a datatable with shiny? Or it would break.

Comment: @firmo23, unfortunately, I am not sure as I do not know how your shiny app is designed. You would only know via trials and errors. Good luck!

Comment: In the scenario of a totally empty list? I think that it should return NULL as well and not a comma.

Comment: @firmo23 in this case, you can add a check if it is empty before creating `myString`.

Comment: Hi Jongkai, is there a way to replace all the NAs where there is no other country to display? For example USA(AL,AR,TX), NA with USA(AL,AR,TX). I tried to replace the NAs with " " after creating the list but it failed so i suppose it can only be achieved through the ifs you created.